# intergating New Firebase.. error cocoapods

Tags: ios, google-analytics, firebase, cocoapods

When i put pod 'Firebase' i dont get the Analytics in it it says the version 2.5.1 and when i say pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

```
Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Analytics` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

When i do pod update Firebase it is stuck for hours at

```
Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance
```

I have tried everything i have updated all my cocoapods version.. i dont know whats the problem..

Code for Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'NewFirebase' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


  pod 'Firebase’
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics’


  target 'NewFirebaseTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'NewFirebaseUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Thanks
Aryan

Comment: can you include your pod file

Comment: I have updated the question :) @Ymmanuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to sync your Cocoapods master repo by running `pod repo update` ([Source Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/cocoapods/firebase-talk/7U9WipcWo_o/kgI42Mp_AwAJ)).

When my sync didn't work, a quick reinstall of Cocoapods fixed the syncing errors.

Answer (score 3):

As it is established here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Firebase analytics are included in Firebase/Core which actually is the only thing included in

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

So you don't need to add   pod 'Firebase/Analytics’ , it doesn't exist

Comment: but when i put this it gives the older version which doesnt have the core or analytics

Comment: Mmm weird... have you tried installing "pod 'Firebase/Core' " because pod 'Firebase/Analytics’ doesn't exist

Comment: have tried everything but thanks for help as i have done it manually :)